# SQL issue with Like operator not working as expected

Tags: sql, teradata-sql-assistant

I have an sql issue using teradata sql-assistant with like operator as is shown in the below exemple:

table A

```
id|
23_0
111_10
201_540
```

so i should select only the id that finish with '_0'

i tried the below query but it give me all the three ids

```
select * from A 
where id like '%_0'
```

but i expect only

```
id|
23_0
```

have you any idea, please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `_` is a special character.  So, one method is:

```
where id like '$_0' escape '$'
```

You can also use `right()`:

```
where right(id, 2) = '_0'
```

Comment: thank you @Gordon Linoff for your reply, i tested the first solution but it seems does not work i got nothing, the second solution i can not use it because i have many id in my real data so i have not only this examples so i can not use right (id,2)

Comment: For your case, still need % wild-card: `where id like '%$_0' escape '$'`